# Book suggestion for learning topology

Tags: book-recommendation

I need a book on elementary topology which is good to read and easy to understand the concepts. Please give me a reference which book should I use..

Answer (score 2):

The standard text seems to be [*Topology* by James Munkres](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131816292). I used it for my point-set topology course and liked it.

Comment: Munkres is pretty good for point set and I liked the basic algebraic topology but the exposition got really dry once he started covering the nitty gritty of algebraic topology. This might be due to the lack of heavyhanded techniques and ideas presented to study topological spaces from the algebraic side of things, though.

Answer (score 0):

Bert Mendelson's Introduction to Topology to Start.
You can try Munkres, but the exercises are in my opinion way too difficult for a first timer.

Comment: I think Munkres' problems are very reasonable. Some are quite challenging and require unique insight but most are doable (or mostly doable) *provided* the reader is comfortable with writing proofs.

Comment: Writing proofs is never a problem. Coming up with them is a problem. His exercises aren't gentle and a beginner or first timer in topology will probably be stuck for hours on each exercise.

Comment: I think you're splitting hairs here.. When I said "comfortable with writing proofs", I clearly meant that the reader has had a few proof-based courses under his/her belt. With enough experience writing proofs, Munkres isn't hard. Especially if one has had real analysis already. It's a lot of the same proofs but with an extra thin layer of abstraction.